# Problem about the average time to search for an exit

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value

The house consists of n rooms (n>4) located at the vertices of a regular polygon with n sides. Adjacent vertexes are connected by corridors. The first vertex contains the output. The person who was in K's room panics and runs through the corridors in search of an exit. In 1 minute, it passes through one corridor. Selects the direction randomly with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ in one direction or in the other Find the mathematical expectation of the exit time.
This formula seems to be valid: $\mathbb{E}[F_k] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[F_{k-1}]+\mathbb{E}[F_{k+1}]}{2} + 1, \mathbb{E}[F_{n+1}] = 0, \mathbb{E}[F_{1}] = 0$

Is this a true fact? How can you strictly argue that this is the case

Comment: So what is $F_k$, exactly? In particular, what is $k$ ?

Comment: $F_k$ random variable - the time it takes for a person to get from room k to the exit

Comment: It's easier to start from the end. It's clear that $F_1 = 0$, because you're already at the exit. And there are only $n$ vertices, so $F_{k}=0$ for $k > n$. But then we get to the equation ... So imagine you're at vertex $k$. How what are your options? You can go clockwise or anti-clockwise, and you choose that randomly, with $1/2$ chance for each. For both of these options, it takes one minute to get to the adjecent vertex, and then you're either at $k-1$ or $k+1$, and essentially the problem starts over. That's the reasoning for the first equation.